# Data mining of twitter

Tags: python, twitter

I am trying to get hold of some data for my masters to establish if quoted facts are true based on my own investigation of twitter responses.  I have spent the last 5 days trying to get python to do what i need it to but i keep failing.

I want to extract and analyse tweets between 2 dates based on various keywords.  If possible then export it to a csv so i can perform further analysis and counts.  If possible even establish location of tweets and also general mood if possible.  I am new to Python so that is not helping.

I am really hoping someone can help get me started or point me to a dummies guide that is actually some use.  I have tried about 8 different books and quite a few different online
resources to no avail.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show us what you have tried so far so we can find you the best solution.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far and the welcome.  After the oAuth i have the following;

Comment: def twitter_search(twitter_api, q, max_results=200, **kw):
   
    search_results = twitter_api.search.tweets(q=q, count=100, **kw)
    
    statuses = search_results['statuses']
    
    max_results = min(1000, max_results)
    
    for _ in range(10):
        try:
            next_results = search_results['search_metadata']['next_results']
        except KeyError, e: 
            break
            
        kwargs = dict([ kv.split('=') 
                        for kv in next_results[1:].split("&") ])

Comment: search_results = twitter_api.search.tweets(**kwargs)
        statuses += search_results['statuses']
        
        if len(statuses) > max_results: 
            break
            
    return statuses

q = "John Lewis hare bear"
results = twitter_search(twitter_api, q, max_results=10)

print json.dumps(results, indent=1)

Comment: This obviously works but it is not between certain dates and is an example i have tweaked to get some results.  Is it even right? Do i need it all? How do i get it to tell me how many tweets there are, and just the tweeters locations or the tweet only etc?  How do i fix the location to be between the dates i need?

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of Twitter Python client libraries that will take care of fetching tweets for you.  You can see them on [Twitter's Developer page](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries).  The docs for each library will show you how to use it, but with any of them all you should have to do is parse the JSON in the API response and then save it and/or do the analysis required.

> If possible even establish location of tweets

If available for the tweet, the geographic information comes back with the JSON representation of the tweet.

> also general mood if possible

People do PhDs in sentiment analysis, so there's no quick answer on how to do that, but as a good tutorial to doing sentiment analysis on Twitter you might have a look at Bill Howe's video lectures from his Intro to Data Science Coursera course.  Sentiment analysis of tweets was one of the assignments, and he walks you through how to get tweets in his setup video and provides some starter code. Check out the videos for the getting started assignment [here](https://class.coursera.org/datasci-001/lecture/55).

Comment: Hi,  Thanks for your post.  Am i right in thinking you cannot get tweets older than 14 days?  Do you know how to get older ones?

Comment: I can't find number in Twitter's API documentation, but they do warn in their API that their search index only goes back a certain amount of time.  Check out the docs for the `util` parameter [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets)

Comment: The link is broken. next time please try to add some of the content of the links in your answers. So if the link becomes invalid your answer will remain helpful.